# How do I correctly offset bootstrap grid columns to center underneath three existing columns?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to achieve the following container grid layout below using Bootstrap 4, which will give me three evenly spaced boxes with another two following underneath evenly centered and spaced:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
        <!-- ======= Services Section ======= -->
    <section id="services" class="services">
      <div class="container">

        <div class="section-title">
          <span>Services</span>
          <h2>Services</h2>
          <p>We are experts in delivering the following services.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 d-flex align-items-stretch" data-aos="fade-up">
            <div class="icon-box">
              <div class="icon"><i class="bx bxl-dribbble"></i></div>
              <h4><a href="">Service one</a></h4>
              <p>Voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 d-flex align-items-stretch mt-4 mt-md-0" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="150">
            <div class="icon-box">
              <div class="icon"><i class="bx bx-file"></i></div>
              <h4><a href="">Service two</a></h4>
              <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 d-flex align-items-stretch mt-4 mt-lg-0" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="300">
            <div class="icon-box">
              <div class="icon"><i class="bx bx-tachometer"></i></div>
              <h4><a href="">Service three</a></h4>
              <p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia</p>
            </div>
          </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-6 d-flex align-items-stretch mt-4 mt-lg-0" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="450"></div>
            <div class="icon-box">
              <div class="icon"><i class="bx bx-world"></i></div>
              <h4><a href="">Service four</a></h4>
              <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis</p>
            </div>
          </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-6 d-flex align-items-stretch mt-4 mt-lg-0" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="450"></div>
            <div class="icon-box">
              <div class="icon"><i class="bx bx-slideshow"></i></div>
              <h4><a href="">Service five</a></h4>
              <p>Quis consequatur saepe eligendi voluptatem consequatur dolor consequuntur</p>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
<!-- ======= End of Services Section ======= -->
```

Here is what my code visually looks like:

[image]

I don't know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Please add a [example].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two mistakes:

1. Card 4 and 5 were outside of the `row`.
2. Card 4 and 5 didn't have any content (the content was outside of the card).

Add `d-flex justify-content-center` to the `row` to center the cards.

See the snippet below.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- ======= Services Section ======= -->
<section id="services" class="services">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="section-title">
      <span>Services</span>
      <h2>Services</h2>
      <p>We are experts in delivering the following services.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 d-flex align-items-stretch" data-aos="fade-up">
        <div class="icon-box">
          <div class="icon"><i class="bx bxl-dribbble"></i></div>
          <h4><a href="">Service one</a></h4>
          <p>Voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 d-flex align-items-stretch mt-4 mt-md-0" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="150">
        <div class="icon-box">
          <div class="icon"><i class="bx bx-file"></i></div>
          <h4><a href="">Service two</a></h4>
          <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 d-flex align-items-stretch mt-4 mt-lg-0" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="300">
        <div class="icon-box">
          <div class="icon"><i class="bx bx-tachometer"></i></div>
          <h4><a href="">Service three</a></h4>
          <p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 d-flex align-items-stretch mt-4 mt-lg-0" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="450">
        <div class="icon-box">
          <div class="icon"><i class="bx bx-world"></i></div>
          <h4><a href="">Service four</a></h4>
          <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 d-flex align-items-stretch mt-4 mt-lg-0" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="450">
        <div class="icon-box">
          <div class="icon"><i class="bx bx-slideshow"></i></div>
          <h4><a href="">Service five</a></h4>
          <p>Quis consequatur saepe eligendi voluptatem consequatur dolor consequuntur</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<!-- ======= End of Services Section ======= -->
```